# how to open files with different extensions programatically in java?

Tags: java, android

i hope you are fine.
i have here a code i took from this site but don't know how to use, after trying different ways without success, so i want to share with you for get a solution.
what i want is using this code to open file in path, so how to define this "files or file" in path in this code.
this is the code :

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(url);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
        // Word document
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
        // PDF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
        // Powerpoint file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
        // Excel file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
        // WAV audio file;
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-wav");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
        // RTF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
        // GIF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
        // JPG file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
        // Text file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
    } else if (url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
        // Video files
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
    } else {
        
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

i tried to define the path as `"String url = "/path/here";` but i get error :
The method fromFile(File) in the type Uri is not applicable for the arguments (String)

i tried to set the path as `File url = ("/path/here");`
and also i get error :
context cannot be resolved

Comment: You need to use `new ClassName(parameters)` when creating an instance of a class. `("/path/here")` is just a string in parentheses. You instead want to use `File url = new File("/path/here");`. You might find it beneficial to read about how types/inheritance works in Java before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would probably be using a map that is built once then looking up the extension.

```java
private static final Map<String, String> FILE_TYPES;

// Static code blocks will only run once during the program's lifetime
// to initialize static fields
static {
    FILE_TYPES = new HashMap<>();

    // Word document
    FILE_TYPES.put("doc", "application/msword");
    FILE_TYPES.put("docx", "application/msword");

    // PDF file
    FILE_TYPES.put("pdf", "application/pdf");

    // Etc.
}
```

Assuming you don't have any extensions with multiple dots in the name (like `.tar.gz`), you could also get a substring and do a simple lookup.

```java
String urlStr = url.toString();
String extension = urlStr.substring(urlStr.lastIndexOf("."));

intent.setDataAndType(uri, FILE_TYPES.getOrDefault(extension, "*/*"));
```

Comment: thank you brother for answering, but how do i specify the file i want to open, now i have your code i set it as you mentioned.
and i get error in the code "FILE_TYPE cannot be resolved".